# Nowhere dense point set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am trying to show for a complete metric space $X$ without isolated points, a set $\{x\}$ consisting of a single point is nowhere dense. I have found the following proof online, but I don't follow it exactly:

Choose an open ball $B$ $x \in B$, so that $B(x,r) \subset X$ for some $r$. Since $x$ is an accumulation point of $X$, there is a point $y \in B(x,r), y \not=x$. Since $B(x,r)$ is open we have $B(y,r_1) \subset B(x,r)$ for some $r_1 >0$. Furthermore for $r_0 = \min\{d(x,y),r_1\}$ we have $x \notin B(y,r_0) \subset B(x,r) \subset B$ which implies the result.

I don't understand where this uses completeness, and where it uses that $X$ has no isolated points

Comment: @HennoBrandsma the exact statement is "Let $X$ be a complete metric space without isolated points, show that any one point set $\{x\}$ is nowhere dense for any $x \in X$"

Comment: I've edited my original post, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need completeness. Nor being metric, only that singleton sets are closed.

The proof is trivial: a set $A$ is nowhere dense iff the interior of $\overline{A}$ is empty. (If you don't know it, prove it. )

And so if singletons are closed they are nowhere dense iff they have empty interior iff they are not an isolated point.

**Added** explaining the proof you cited:

Completeness is still not needed. There the other definition of nowhere denseness of $A$ is used: $A$ is nowhere dense iff for every non-empty open set $O$ there is some non-empty open $O' \subseteq O$ such that $O' \cap A = \emptyset$.

So $A = \{x\}$ this translates to : for every non-empty open set $O$ there is a smaller open set $O' \subseteq O$ such that $x \notin O'$. In proving this we can assume WLOG that $x \in O$, or else we take $O ' = O$ and we're done.

In a metric space we can moreover use open balls (as they form a base), so then we just have to show that for every open ball/set $B$ that contains $x$, there is a ball $B(y,r') \subseteq B$ that does not contain $x$.

So the proof starts with $B$ containing $x$, and $B(x,r) \subseteq B$. Then $B(x,r) \neq \{x\}$ (which is the same as saying that $x$ is an accumulation point of $X$), because $x$ is not an isolated point (this is where it used). So $y \neq x$ exists in $B(x,r)$.

As $B(x,r)$ is open we have some ball $B(y,r_1) \subseteq B(x,r)$ as well.

Then take $r_0 \leq r_1$ and $r_0 < d(x,y)$, so that $x \notin B(y,r_0)$ (this in fact proves that $\{x\}$ is closed, which is what I use in the short general proof), and $B(y,r_0) \subseteq B(y,r_1) \subseteq B(x,r) \subseteq B$.

So we see the closedness of singletons and the non-isolated point assumptions being used here as well. But the metric is quite irrelevant really. As is completeness.

Comment: could you explain how being an isolated point means the closure has empty interior?

Comment: **not** an isolated point. The interior of a singleton is empty or the singleton. If the latter, it's an isolated point. Which we assumed not to have. So it's always empty